# adding node port to an exciting istio service

Tags: kubernetes, istio, calico

I created a local kubernetes cluster with a master and 2 workers using VM(ubuntu 16.04)
I am also using calico for networking and I am exploring istio for the moment.
my problem is the ingress load balancer doesn't get an external IP. to my understanding I should use a node port to access the ingress load balancer but I can find how to do so.
should I have done it when installing, can I add it now and how?

kubernetes version :  v1.11.1
calico version : v3.1
istio version : 0.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If don't have a service attached to your deployment, you can use `kubectl expose`:

```
kubectl expose deployment istio --type=NodePort --name=istio-service
```

If you already deployed a service, you can edit the service spec and add `type: "NodePort"` the quickest way to do this is using `kubectl patch`:

```
kubectl patch svc istio-service -p '{"spec":{"type":"NodePort"}}'
```

More info about NodePort services can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/)